# What exactly does this piece of code mean? (spread syntax, .map, .dataset.filter)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out what exactly this piece of code means. But I can't figure out why that spread syntax(`...document.querySelectorAll`) is used and what the `.map` and the `.dataset.filter` does.

```
const filters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn.active')].map(
    (el) => el.dataset.filter,
  );
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` **does not return an array**. The spread here is to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) here is to convert the resulting NodeList from `querySelectorAll` into an array so we can use `map`. NodeList by itself does not have `map`, only `forEach`, hence the conversion.

[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) is a property that contains all of the `data-*` attributes - here we are getting `data-filter`. See the below snippet for an example.

```js
const filters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn.active')]
  .map((el) => el.dataset.filter);
  
console.log(filters); // ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

```html
<div class="btn active" data-filter="foo"></div>
<div class="btn active" data-filter="bar"></div>
<div class="btn active" data-filter="baz"></div>
```